# Microsoft office version

Tags: microsoft-office

I have a microsoft office installed on two computers, both report they are SP3 but have different build numbers

11.8307.8221 and 11.8169.8172 (you can see the later identified as SP3 here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821549 , which is confirmed in the about box)

My question is , how do I find out why the versions are different even though they are both reporting SP3.

What could I download to move 11.8169.8172 to 11.8307.8221? (I've tried downloading SP3 for Office again on the machine with 11.8169.8172 but during installation I am told I have the latest version)

Answer (score 3):

Use Microsoft Update to obtain any patches released after SP3, even though they are both SP3, there may be some patches missing on one of them.